# Append (Concatenate) HTML Element To React props Value

Tags: reactjs, append, concatenation, jsx, react-props

I've a JSX like below. The below code is Working (Multiple Ternary Conditionals).

```
<div className="myClassName">
                     {this.props.addr? this.props.addr.phoneno : '' }
                     {this.props.addr? (<span
                             className='location'>
                             {this.props.addr.location}
                      </span>) : ''}
                  </div>
```

When I tried with below Syntax with a single Ternary Operator, I'm getting Error.

```
<div className="myClassName">
                     {this.props.addr? this.props.addr.phoneno (<span
                             className='location'>
                             {this.props.addr.location}
                      </span>) : '' }

                  </div>
```

All I wanted is to append a Span Element with `phoneno` value. How to do Proper Concatenation here in this Example??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React doesn't allow returning multiple child elements inside a block. So to solve this you can use `React.Fragment`. There's more explanation about Fragments [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html).
Below is the corrected syntax.

```
<div className="myClassName">
     {this.props.addr ? (
     <React.Fragment>
        {this.props.addr.phoneno}
        <span className='location'>
           {this.props.addr.location}
        </span>
      </React.Fragment>) : '' }
</div>
```